# How to properly add a Navigation Controller to my Search View with hidden Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When my app is launched the first screen (view) the user sees when my app is launched is a search form without any navigation. Navigation will show up after search process is done and results are ready to be displayed. Where I'm stuck at is the proper way to make it work with the navigation controller.

So, assuming the app name is RealEsateProperties

In RealEsatePropertiesAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RealEsatePropertiesViewController;

@interface RealEsatePropertiesAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
        UINavigationController *ListingNav;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) RealEsatePropertiesViewController *viewController;

// Then I added this line for the navigation
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *ListingNav;


@end
```

and in RealEsatePropertiesAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "RealEsatePropertiesAppDelegate.h"
#import "RealEsatePropertiesViewController.h"

@synthesize window=_window;

@synthesize window=_viewController;

@synthesize ListingNav;

@implementation RealEsatePropertiesAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLanchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

// Iadded the following 4 lines to try making the navigation thing work without showing any navigation bar on the first screen (that is the search form)
self.ListingNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:self.viewController];
self.ListingNav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self.window addSubView:ListingNav.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}

@end
```

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: is the navigation bar appear on the first screen? or it doesn't appear at all through out the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create/alloc your RealEsatePropertiesViewController ?

```
viewController = [[RealEsatePropertiesViewController alloc] init];
```